# Convert List<Object[]> to a user defined List objects List<EcomDto> in java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have List<Object[]> data in which object array length is 7 and data of array are combination of different types. (i.e. string, date, enum and long)

I have one DTO class (EcomDto.java) in which I want to set data which I read from above object[].
I am doing it by using if else statement like:

```
List<Object[]> data=getActualData();//
List<EcomDto> response=new ArrayList<>();
EcomDto dto=null;
for(Object[] obj:data){
 dto=new EcomDto();
 if(obj[0]!=null){
 dto.setZeroIndexData((String)obj[0]);
}
if(obj[1]!=null){
 dto.setFirstIndexData((Long)obj[1]);
}
if(obj[2]!=null){
 dto.setSecondIndexData((UserDefinedEnum)obj[2]);
}
}
```

Can this be improved in some way?

Tried to do in stream way, but I am not much familiar with Java streams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Stream#map` to create the new `List` of DTOs from the `data` list, but there's not much that can be done to simplify the creation of the `EcomDto` objects.

```java
var response = data.stream().map(obj -> {
    EcomDto dto = new EcomDto();
    if (obj[0] != null) dto.setZeroIndexData((String) obj[0]);
    if (obj[1] != null) dto.setFirstIndexData((Long) obj[1]);
    if (obj[2] != null) dto.setSecondIndexData((UserDefinedEnum) obj[2]);
    return dto;
}).toList();
```